# How to modify mesh after sculpting with multiresolution modifier?

Tags: sculpt, multiresolution

I've created a character and sculpted them to an extend I like them.  I realize now, however, that I did not model the inside of the mouth.  When I try and extrude from meshes, it screws up the normals badly.  How do I modify a mesh after using multires?

Answer (score 1):

The *Multires* modifier does not like changes on the low-poly base mesh very much. It can mess up the high-poly levels and add spikes and other abnormalities.

You can try to select and separate the new extruded mesh, remove the *Multires* modifier from the separated mesh, then join it again with the body object (that has the *Multires* modifier). Make the body object the active object (selected last) to keep the *Multires* modifier.

If this doesn't work then it's time for plan B.

**Plan B: Shrinkwrap**
Make a copy of the original unchanged object, remove the *Multires* modifier from the copy, add the inside of the mouth to the copy, add the *Multires* modifier. Finally, add a *Shrinkwrap* modifier and shrinkwrap it to the original mesh to transfer the sculpted details. For a better result use *Wrap Method* `Project`, and tick the `Negative` checkbox (project direction). Then apply the *Shrinkwrap* modifier.

Example videos:

1. [Blender Sculpting Tutorial: Full Advanced Creature Creation Workflow](https://youtu.be/tQfFlzHJJ88?t=1947)
2. [Projecting High-Res Models in Blender 2.8 using Shrinkwrap](https://youtu.be/1CiQxc1QvRM)  (use a *Multires* modifier not a *Subdivision Surface* modifier like in this video)

Comment: But won't that wrap the inside of the mouth as well?

Comment: Yes, it would. But you can separate the inside of the mouth directly after the lips and move it to a separate object (key P). Select the edge loop around the lips, mark it a seam (key U), then you can select the inside with *Select Linked* (key L).  Limited selection to seams in the popup. Done this, use the ShrinkWrap modifier on the head, and join the objects again if you're done. The same is recommended for the eye sockets if your model has them.